# Gspred - How do you select 2 separate columns in one call?

Tags: gspread

I'd like to select 2 columns (A and H) from a Google Spreadsheet in one API call - is it doable? I can't seem to get it working with `batch_get`.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I've figured it out:

datatable.batch_get(["A2:A", "H2:H"])